# Customize X-Axis for high stock chart

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, highcharts

Hi I am trying to customize high stock chart column for making it x-axis date driven rather than data driven.

Currently as mentioned in [Filldle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/aalok25/wkmkkwrr/3/)

```
rangeSelector: {
    selected: 0,
    inputEnabled: true
},
```

Do we need to add something here?

I want my x-axis to be like this example

[Example link](http://jsfiddle.net/aalok25/J6H7f/60/)

```
xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        type: 'datetime',
         labels: {
            style: {
                fontFamily: 'Tahoma'
            },

            rotation: -45,
         }
    },
```

We see that from and to date are data driven and X-Axis adjust accordingly.
I want a scenario like if I want to show data for thirty days, than i can set x-axis to 5 days interval and likewise other configurable depending on number of days I want to show.

Also is there a way to set initial from and to date on your own rather than data driven.

Is it necessary to pass x axis as epoch time cant be pass simple date

Also wanted to know:

Is Licensee for high stock charts and high chart different?
If we buy licensee for high chart can we use high stock charts too?

Comment: To answer you second question, you can use Highstock JS for a personal or non-profit project for free under the Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0 License http://shop.highsoft.com/highstock.html

Comment: @chridam I am having licensee for high chart I want to know do i need to have anything for using high stock charts

Comment: @AlokAgarwal - you need a HighStock license if not for non-profit use. Two different licenses.

Comment: You can edit xAxis labels by http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats